# Performing 2 async AJAX request, one after the other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Firstly, I know the title seems to contradict itself.

However, my issue is that I want to either call 2 AJAX functions one after the other OR call just the second one.

Let me put this into context.. I am writing a "store locator" application. By default all the results are loaded in alphabetical order. A user is able to enter their address or postcode into a box and hit search. My application will then find their latitude and longitude coordinates from their input using Google's geocoding API and then pass these coordinates into my own AJAX call which will then order the results based on their location, closest store first.

However, if the user does not enter a postcode I want to just go back to the default and show the results in alphabetical order once again.

So far...

```
    function generateResults(_postcode) {
        //console.log("generating results");
        if (readyState) {
            changeReadyState(false);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + encodeURIComponent(_postcode) + ",UK&sensor=false",
                success: function(d){
                    var _u = ajax_url;

                    if (d.results && d.results[0] && d.results[0].geometry && d.results[0].geometry.location) {
                        var location = d.results[0].geometry.location;
                        _u = appendQS(_u, "lat=" + location.lat); // Appends as query string, putting either ? or & before
                        _u = appendQS(_u, "lng=" + location.lat);

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: _u,
                            success: function(data){

                                changeReadyState(true);
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                changeReadyState(true);
                            },
                            async: false
                        });
                    }
                    else if (d.error_message) {
                        alert(d.error_message);
                        changeReadyState(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("No results found for '" + _postcode + "'");
                        postcodeTxt.val("");
                        changeReadyState(true);
                    }

                },
                error: function(){
                    changeReadyState(true);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            //console.log("Application busy, try again soon");
        }
    }
```

I suppose I could just have two cases depending on whether the `_postcode` is empty or not but this would mean repeating code.

Basically I want to only call the Google Geocoding API if the `_postcode` field is not empty, but I want to ensure that this call is either not going ahead or has finished before I call my own AJAX.

I had a look at making the first request synchronous but according to the jQuery docs, it's been deprecated and they recommend using their success/error/complete callbacks instead.

I've a feeling it's just a bit late in the day!

Cheers

Comment: use some type of call back, most AJAX API's have not just the success: function () {} callback but a complete: as well. You could use the complete: {} method to trigger your second call to ensure they aren't triggering together.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$.when(
    $.get('path1', function(d1) {
        // do stuff with first request data
    }, 'datatype')
).then(function() {
    $.get('path2', function(d2) {
        // do stuff with second request data
    }, 'datatype')
}, function(o,e,m) {
    // handle errors
});
```

You can even do more than just ajax calls if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this may be getting on the right track. However, I'm not sure this takes into account whether or not `postcode` is empty. I want to do something like `if (postcode != "") { // synchronous AJAX call to get lat, lng } // asynchronous AJAX call to get nearest stores using lat, lng or stores in default order`